# Looking for a List of LAPACK/BLAS Error code

Tags: lapack, blas, error-code

I am using zheev of LAPACK (in Intel MKL). I got `int INFO=99`. I've been searching around internet what this corresponds to, but I cannot find the documentation with list of all the integer error code and their meaning.

Does anyone have links to the complete list of LAPACK/BLAS error codes? Or if you have one off line, could you copy and paste as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation of LAPACK](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node136.html), the output `INFO` reports two kinds of error. On the one hand, if `INFO<0`, parameter `-INFO` has an illegal value. Parameters are numbered as 1,2,3,... : no 0 (Fortran). For instance, the size of the matrix is negative.  On the other hand, **`INFO>0` reports [a computational failure](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node138.html).**

**The actual reason for the failure is described in the comments of the routine prompting the error.** For instance, for [`zheev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/dee/zheev_8f_source.html), it is written:

> 0:  if INFO = i, the algorithm failed to converge; i off-diagonal elements of an intermediate tridiagonal form did not converge to zero.

Looking at the source of [`zheev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/dee/zheev_8f_source.html), the matrix is scaled, reduced to trigonal form and then either the eigenvectors are not required and `dsterf()` is called, or the eigenvectors are to be computed and `zungtr()` is called to form a unitary matrix Q starting from the reflectors and `zsteqr()` is called to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the tridiagonal matrix. The output INFO is therefore set by either `dsterf()` or `zsteqr()`.

Regarding [`zsteqr()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d25/zsteqr_8f_source.html#l00134), the value of INFO is incremented at line 536, each time an error remains non-null after the maximum number of iterations. Some cases potentially leading to failure of QR iterations are reported in section 1.3.6 Failure of Global convergence in [Numerical Methods for General and Structured Eigenvalue Problems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540245469) by Daniel Kressner. **Nevertheless, [the errors are often due to programming error](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node138.html) listed as**:

- wrong type of array. For instance, `zheev()` expects arrays of double precision complex, that is `DOUBLE COMPLEX` or `COMPLEX*16` in Fortran. If `COMPLEX*8` is used, it likely leads to undefined behavior and it might result in positive INFO.
- the arrays (matrix and vectors) could have been corrupted before running the LAPACK routine. For `zheev()`, it might be induced by INF or NaN in the array.
- a programming error occurred in calling the routine. For instance, the argument `LDA` is the leading dimension of the array `A`. It is checked that LDA >= max(1,N) and it returns `INFO=-5` if this condition is not enforced. Nevertheless, nothing prevents the programmer from allocating and array `A` or size `n*n` and specifying `LDA=2*n`, which would result in undefined behavior, as array index out of bound will be used. Again, a possible behavior is returning `INFO=99`.

Finally, the LAPACKE wrapper of LAPACK for langage C/C++ automatically cares for allocation of work arrays. As a result, it also defines error codes, such as `LAPACK_WORK_MEMORY_ERROR` and `LAPACK_TRANSPOSE_MEMORY_ERROR`, returned in `info`, in lapacke.h:

```
#define LAPACK_WORK_MEMORY_ERROR       -1010
#define LAPACK_TRANSPOSE_MEMORY_ERROR  -1011
```

Do not hesitate to ask a question on StackOverflow, reporting the error and a significant piece of code, along with a description of the unwanted behavior. Ideally, the piece of code is a sample code reproducing the error. But a piece of code showing allocation of arrays and values of inputs can prove sufficient.